# Perform complex jsonpath query

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I have the following json response. I want to filter using json path as follows:
Get the first date for person `ec7e231e-1fed-4860-a1ab-c2e3248a183e` where 1. the date is not null and 2. the exam array is empty and 3. the absent flag is false

```
[
  {
    "Person": {
      "ReferenceKey": "ec7e231e-1fed-4860-a1ab-c2e3248a183e",
      "fname": "john",
      "lname": "anderson",
      "adress": null
    },
    "days": [
      {
        "date": null,
        "absent": false,
        "holiday": false,
        "exam": [],
        "blockingtimes": []
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-02-19",
        "absent": false,
        "holiday": false,
        "exam": [],
        "blockingtimes": []
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-02-20",
        "absent": false,
        "holiday": false,
        "exam": [],
        "blockingtimes": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Person": {
      "ReferenceKey": "ec7e231e-1fed-4860-a1ab-c2e3248a1900",
      "fname": "manny",
      "lname": "panny",
      "adress": null
    },
    "days": [
      {
        "date": null,
        "absent": false,
        "holiday": false,
        "exam": [],
        "blockingtimes": []
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-02-19",
        "absent": false,
        "holiday": false,
        "exam": [],
        "blockingtimes": []
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-02-20",
        "absent": true,
        "holiday": false,
        "exam": [],
        "blockingtimes": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so far i was only able to retrieve all person uuids `$..person.mitarbeiterReferenceKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$.[?(@.Person.ReferenceKey == 'ec7e231e-1fed-4860-a1ab-c2e3248a183e')].days[?(@.date != null && @.absent == false && @.exam.length() == 0)])
```

[image]

More information:

- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)